# Remove underline from h text inside a element using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble removing the automatic browser underlining of my text in the following code.

```
<div class="section-one">

        <div class="row products-top-row">
         <a href="product_main.php?cat=Dress" class="col span-1-of-2 product-dress-image-main">
          <div>
           <h2>Dresses</h2>
          </div>   
         </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

In my CSS file I have tried the following, which I thought would work:

```
.product-dress-image-main a {

text-decoration: none;    

}
```

I have also attempted:

```
.product-dress-image-main a:active,
.product-dress-image-main a:hover,
.product-dress-image-main a:visited,
.product-dress-image-main a:link {

text-decoration: none;    

}
```

I have even gone so far as to try doing a global:

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

None of these work, but when I add the styling directly (as seen in the below example), it does remove the underline? Why will it not do it in the CSS doc? I assume I may be messing something up with my hierarchy.

```
<div class="section-one">

    <div class="row products-top-row">
     <a href="product_main.php?cat=Dress" class="col span-1-of-2 product-dress-image-main" style="text-decoration:none">
      <div>
       <h2>Dresses</h2>
      </div>   
     </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

FYI - the reason I have the div contained within the  element is that I am using the entire div element as a link (clickable picture on a homepage to take customer to a product page).

Any advice is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS is targeting the `<a/>` as a child of .product-dress-image-main. This should work:

```
a.product-dress-image-main {
    text-decoration: none;    
}
```

**For more information:**
 [CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: I ran your example in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vv9gz02e/) and it looks good; have an upvote.

Comment: Smashed it! thanks dude... you don't by any chance have any good learning links or materials I could read on selecting child/parent relationships in CSS?... not too sure I fully understand the answer!. Basically are you saying that by using "a.class-name" I am now selecting the a element as the parent and applying the style to all elements in side it (e.g. the <h> element)?

Comment: @basil3 I've added a reference to the answer.

Comment: Thanks :) massive help!

Answer (score 0):

you can do as

```css
.section-one .row .col {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-one">

  <div class="row products-top-row">
    <a href="product_main.php?cat=Dress" class="col span-1-of-2 product-dress-image-main">
      <div>
        <h2>Dresses</h2>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps